# How to put a title for each of my pages with this code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've asked for help recently here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58544/forum-sign-up-and-sign-in-software/58552#58552 and a person has restructured my code to make it better organized. I would like to know how I can put a title for each of my pages using this:

index.php:

```
<?php
# Select the title
switch(trim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])){
    case "members":         $title = "Members";         break;
    case "sign_up":         $title = "Sign Up";         break;
    case "sign_in":         $title = "Sign In";         break;
    case "change_theme":    $title = "Change Theme";    break;
    case "contact_us":      $title = "Contact Us";      break;
    case "help":            $title = "Help";            break;
    case "rules":           $title = "Rules";           break;
    default:                $title = "Forums";          break;
}

# Define the page name and check for empty value
$arr = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); $page_name = array_pop($arr);
if(empty($page_name)) $page_name = "index.php";

# Select the sidecase
$sidecase = "";
switch(trim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])){
    case 'index': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15">Forums</h1>';
        $sidecase .= '<h3 id="category_title">Categories</h3>';
    } break;
    case 'members': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15">Members</h1>';
    } break;
    case 'sign_up': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15" style="text-align: center;">Sign Up</h1>';
    } break;
    case 'sign_in': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15" style="text-align: center;">Sign In</h1>';
    } break;
    case 'change_theme': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15">Change Theme</h1>';
    } break;
    case 'contact_us': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15">Contact Us</h1>';
    } break;
    case 'help': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 class="h1_marg_b15">Help</h1>';
    } break;
    case 'rules': {
        $sidecase .= '<h1 style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Rules</h1>';
        $sidecase .= '<p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu nibh turpis. Nunc sit amet auctor elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In malesuada lobortis tempus. Integer auctor condimentum sapien, non scelerisque eros cursus et. In vel leo elementum, iaculis tellus sit amet, vestibulum quam. Etiam dapibus pulvinar risus, vestibulum rhoncus sapien commodo vitae. Etiam sit amet ultrices dui. Suspendisse luctus fringilla eros. Nam vitae metus porttitor, sagittis arcu eleifend, malesuada odio. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>';
        $sidecase .= '<p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Pellentesque id velit a elit porttitor sollicitudin et vulputate nisl. Donec eu purus non libero porta malesuada et non lorem. Vestibulum ultrices vitae elit vitae accumsan. Quisque euismod, quam sed ornare ultrices, magna mi posuere massa, vel placerat ipsum est quis erat. Aliquam non libero mauris. Etiam ligula velit, commodo et feugiat ac, porta eu orci. Donec laoreet ipsum in urna auctor, vitae malesuada nibh consequat. Donec sit amet libero vitae erat rhoncus venenatis. Maecenas nec pretium justo, eget fermentum tellus. Ut aliquet tellus venenatis posuere fermentum. Fusce mattis velit et tellus suscipit consectetur.</p>';
    } break;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test - <?php echo $title; ?></title>

        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style>
            .h1_marg_b15{
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- TOP BAR -->
        <div id="top_bar">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="top_bar_links">
                    <ul>
                    <li id="home">
                        <a href="../">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="<?php echo ($page_name=="index.php")?"active":"";?>" href=".">Forums</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="<?php echo ($page_name=="members.php")?"active":"";?>" href="members.php">Members</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <div id="header">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <a href=".">Test</a>
                </h1>
                <div id="member_links">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="sign_up">
                            <a href="sign_up.php">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="sign_in">
                            <a href="sign_in.php">Sign In</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CONTAINER -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="breadcrumb_top">
                    <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $sidecase; ?>
                <div id="breadcrumb_bottom">
                    <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footer_links">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="change_theme">
                            <a href="change_theme.php">Change Theme</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="contact_us">
                            <a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="help">
                            <a href="help.php">Help</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="rules">
                            <a href="rules.php">Rules</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p id="footer_copyright">Forum software coded by Dylan - 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently, all my pages have the title "Test – Forums".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy.

You can use `__FILE__`.

Replace the first first Switch() statement with the code below, but make sure that to show the title properly, the case statement should be equal to the value of page. For example, if you are in rules.php, the title would be shown was "Test - Rules"

```
$page = basename(__FILE__, ".php");
switch($page) {
    case "members":         $title = "Members";         break;
    case "sign_up":         $title = "Sign Up";         break;
    case "sign_in":         $title = "Sign In";         break;
    case "change_theme":    $title = "Change Theme";    break;
    case "contact_us":      $title = "Contact Us";      break;
    case "help":            $title = "Help";            break;
    case "rules":           $title = "Rules";           break;
    default:                $title = "Forums";          break;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I replaced your code with my code, but the title for rules.php do not change: http://prntscr.com/47yxr2

Comment: Hm, okay, update the code and tell me what is echoed in rules.php

Comment: I've added an echo statement to check whether it's correct. Goto rules.php and say me what it echo's.

Comment: So, the rules.php file just includes index.php?

Comment: Ok, since it is just including the index.php, put the above code before the include, and remove it on the index.php and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, look at the full code. It's this person who has rebuilt all my code from before: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58544/forum-sign-up-and-sign-in-software/58552#58552 I can't give a title for each of my pages.

Comment: This does not work, do you want my FTP access to see what you can do?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the php extension in the `switch` statement something like this: `case "members.php" : $title = "Members";         break;`, first at all you must print the value of the `trim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` variable before get evaluated in the `switch` and then made a choice

Comment: If you want just the filename without .php, use `basename(__FILE__, '.php');`

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not seem very efficient. You can use

```
basename(__FILE__, '.php')
```

as your switch case. Also, you have 2 switch statements that switch on pretty much the same parameter. Try using this as your switch statement

**Complete PHP**

Here is your [complete code](http://pastebin.com/jC2VTceH)

Comment: `basename(__FILE__).PHP_EOL . '.php'`?

Comment: I fixed your entire code. Everything should be working.